# Return types of main function in C as character return type

Tags: c

Can Main function be defined as Character return  type? and what are the other different return type we can use for main function?

Answer (score 2):

C programs can only return `int` while being standards compliant, the only valid signatures are

```
int main(void) { ... }
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char **argv) { ... }
```

However many compilers offer others as extensions, such extensions are allowed by the standard but are not guaranteed to be portable between compilers or platforms.

Answer (score 0):

Only `int` is accepted by any good compiler unless you use an extension or Microsoft crud.

The only standards compliant signatures for `main` are:

```
int main(void);
```

and

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]);
```

the first taking command line parameters and the second not.

---

In c++ the first signature would be written like this:

```
int main();
```

instead